# Optimistic update for a deletion mutation

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I'm writing a deletion mutation. The mutation should delete a `Key` node and update the `viewer`'s `keys` collection (I'm using Relay-style collections: `viewer { keys(first: 3) { edges { node { ... }}}}`.

Following the advice [here](http://blog.pathgather.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-relay-mutations), I'm using the `FIELDS_CHANGE` config for simplicity, and it's actually working:

```
export class DeleteKeyMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer { id }
    `,
  };
  getMutation() { return Relay.QL`mutation {deleteKey}`; }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.id,
    };
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteKeyPayload {
        viewer { keys }
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [
      {
        type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
        fieldIDs: {
          viewer: this.props.viewer.id,
        },
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

Now, how should I write an optimistic mutation for this? I've tried different approaches but none worked.

Answer (score 3):

Optimistic update in Relay is just a simulation of what the server will return if operation succeeds. In your case you are removing one key, meaning the result would be an object without that key.

```
getOptimisticUpdate() {
  return {
    viewer: {
      id: this.props.viewer.id,
      keys: {
        edges: this.props.viewer.keys.edges.filter((keyEdge) => key.node.id !== this.props.id)
      }
    }
  };
}
```

You will also need to include the keys to your fragments so they are available in the mutation.

```
static fragments = {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Viewer { id, keys { edges(first: 3) { node { id } }}
  `,
};
```

The problem with this approach is that it relies on your mutation to know what's your current keys pagination. If you are operating on the whole Connection at once, it is fine, but if you are using Relay pagination you should consider using other mutation operations.

There is `NODE_DELETE`, which can delete all occurrences of your key from Relay store or you can use `RANGE_DELETE` to only delete it from your current connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work: 1) I believe there is a typo in the mutation fragment, which should be `{ id, keys{ edges(first ...`; 2) A warning appears when the optimistic update is added: `warning.js:44 Warning: RelayQueryWriter: Could not find a type name for record `Vmlld2VyOm1l`.` (it disappears if I add `__typename: 'Viewer'` to the optimistic response); and 3) unfortunately no update occurs. Should I open an issue on this?

Comment: I managed to write optimistic responses for update mutations, but not for delete mutations

Comment: Debugging step by step, I see that the RelayQueryWriter does not call `_writeConnection()` in the optimistic update (as it does in the final update), but rather `_writeLink()` on the `keys` field. Apparently the metadata of the `keys` field in the query has `isConnection: false`, any idea why?

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure why it's not applied. I guess in this case you'd need to add 'RANGE_DELETE' or 'NODE_DELETE' config to do this kind of mutation.

Comment: Well, finally I've managed to do it with `NODE_DELETE`! Thanks!

Comment: @GuillermoGrau could u post a gist with ur final solution?